# how to convert tensorflow tensor to numpy array from given example?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to compute Fast Fourier Transform (fft2d) but the following code provides the error:

```
print("type(pred[2]): ", type(pred[2]))
pred[2] = tf.make_ndarray(pred[2])
fft2_pre = np.fft.fft2(pred[2])
```

The error and output:

```
type(pred[2]):  <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'tensor_shape'
```

how it could be solved?

Comment: Here, I am using tensorflow version= 2.4.1

Comment: first cast this tensor to a some tensor_dtype...
This what you are trying to a tensor is a tensor-object, 
first cast it tf.cast(pred[2], dtype=your_datatype) then convert it to a numpy array because tf.make_ndarray() do not work with a tensor object.

Comment: there is no need to convert into ndarray if that could be casted as complex64, how do I cast it into complex64?

Comment: tf.cast(pred[2], dtype=tf.complex64)

Comment: thank you, that works fine to me by using following code: temp = tf.cast(pred[2], tf.complex64)
                    fft2_pre = tf.signal.fft(temp)

Comment: then kindly upvote my comments...

Comment: I don't know how to upvote your comments, could you please inform me?

Comment: push the triangle icon which is on the left of the each comment of mine.

Comment: I am not getting any triangle icon at left or starting of comment instead of flag icon, please post the answer so that I can upvote it by using the triangle icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
temp = tf.cast(pred[2], dtype=tf.complex64)
temp = tf.signal.fft(temp)
```